# c++ issues with inputting/outputting XOR'ed strings

Tags: c++, encryption, cin, getline, xor

I'm a beginner to c++ and I was working on an XOR encryption program. My program works fine when I manually input the code into my program. The issue occurs when I try to decrypt an encrypted phrase and the program only returns the first word of the phrase.

Example:
Inputted string to encrypt: hello world

Key: q

Encrypted string:V

Inputted string to decrypt: V

Key: q

Output: hello

It only gives me back the first word and I think it has something to do with the way I'm taking input and output.

Thank you so much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
/*Encrypt/decrypt program that takes in a string and encrypts it using a single byte xor encryption. Program can also decrypt a given string with or without a key.*/

string XOR(string input, char key){
    string XORString = input;
    string newXOR = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length();i++){
       newXOR += XORString[i]^(int(key+i))%255;
    }
    return newXOR;
}

int main()
{
    /*char key = 'q';
    std::cout << XOR("hello world",key);
    return 0;
   The lines above are for manual testing if needed*/
    bool b = true;
    while(b){
        int x;
        cout<<"Enter 1 for Encryption, 2 for Decryption, 3 for Decryption without key or 4 to end program."<<endl;
        cin>>x;
        if(x==1){
            string phrase1 = "";
            cout<< "Enter a phrase to encrypt: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(std::cin,phrase1);
            cout<<"Enter a key to encrypt with: ";
            char key1;
            cin>> key1;
            std::cout << XOR(phrase1,key1)<< endl;
       }
        else if(x==2){
            string phrase = "";
            cout<< "Enter a phrase to decrypt: ";
            cin.ignore();
            std::getline(std::cin,phrase);
            cout<<"Enter a key to decrypt with: ";
            char key2;
            cin>>key2;
            std::cout << XOR(phrase,key2)<<endl;
        }
        else if(x==3){
            char keys [] = {'!','"','#','$','%','&','(',')','*','+',',','-','.','/','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',':',';','<','=','>','?','@','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','[',']','^','_','`','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','I','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','{','|','}','~'};
            int end = 92;
            int count = 0;
            string s;
            cout<< "Enter phrase: ";
            cin>>s;
            for(int i = 0; i < 92;i++){
                count++;
                cout<<count<<" possible combination out of " << end << " using " << keys[i]<< ":"<<XOR(s,keys[i])<<endl;
            }
        }
        else if(x==4){
            cout<<"Have a nice day!";
            b = false;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"You entered an invalid number";
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

This might be the problem code:

```
            string phrase1 = "";
            cout<< "Enter a phrase to encrypt: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(std::cin,phrase1);
```

Comment: Does `^` have higher precedence than `%`? Save yourself and your readers much pain by adding the parentheses.

Comment: This is probably an issue with XOR'ing with a character. If the character is equal you will generate a null character (a control character) which means end of string in C/C++. XOR is for binary; you should either handle or encode the resulting binary agair *or* you should use another encryption scheme such as modular addition

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your string XORString function try this:

```
//change this
newXOR += XORString[i]^(int(key+i))%255;
//to
newXOR = XORString[i];
```

I hope this solves the problem I don't know much about operator exclusive OR but I think that is causing the problem in the string function

Comment: If it doesn't work please tell me so I can try to find another way to solve it.